# problem creating windows package using jpackage in windows 10?

Tags: java, javafx, java-14, jpackage

I am using openjdk 14.0.1

i have been following the tutorial

https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#install-javafx

Following the tutorial for Runtime images Modular from CLI

i have successfully created the runtime image using jlink. The created runtime image is as follows and using the jvm inside the bin i can run this application.

[image]

In order to create the package from this runtime

i am using the command

```
jpackage --runtime-image hellofx --module hellofx/hellofx.HelloFX
```

This creates an installer as shown below

[image]

but when i run the installer a sound comes and nothing happens. If i open the installer again the same happens i.e sound and nothing happens. So i am wondering whether i am doing the process correctly. I appreciate any help! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out it installed silently. When the installer is run it runs and exits quickly. So there was no confirmation that made it look like an error. Today when i checked the program files, i found the app was installed and also it runs. Thanks!

[image]